# Can I use jQuery global eval intsead of eval to escape from content security policy

Tags: javascript, jquery, content-security-policy

I have used eval but disallowing it by applying CSP. But I am looking for an alternative to it.

I found the function `jQuery.globaleval()`.

```js
jQuery.readyException = function( error ) {
    window.setTimeout( function() {
        throw error; 
    });
};
```

throws:

> Uncaught EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' http://localhost:6060/WCUSTODY/ http://localhost:6060/application/scripts

So, can we use global eval as an alternative to eval, should also accepted by CSP (Content Security Policy).

Comment: Why would that code you provided use eval and throw that error?

Comment: Have you read [the documentation for `jQuery.globalEval()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.globaleval/#jQuery-globalEval-code-options)? You'll note they specifically talk about using a nonce for CSP...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`jQuery.globaleval()` behaves differently from using a normal JavaScript `eval()` in that it's executed within the global context. For example

```
function test() {
  jQuery.globalEval( "var newVar = true;" );
}
test();
```

The variable called `newVar` is in the scope of global. It can be accessed accross the script of your application.

You can use `eval()` without `jQuery.globaleval()` in CSP by setting unsafe-eval as a allowed source.

Similar to like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'unsafe-eval'">
```

If you don't want to use the eval then you can use `new Function()`. By best practices you should avoid `eval()` and `new Function()`

Comment: Actually i am looking for general alternate to my eval, because don't want to allow eval in my application.

Comment: but here you are mentioned question as how to escape eval from csp?

Comment: Right, but in secure way.. unsafe eval is the way but using this any one can bypass security.

Comment: for that case you can use new Function() instead of eval. Please look at my updated answer.